# Can I use potassium ferricyanide instead of potassium ferrocyanide for the identification of calcium?

Tags: inorganic-chemistry, everyday-chemistry, identification

I have to perform the identification test of calcium ion in calcium gluconate. I do not have potassium ferrocyanide for the test but I do have potassium ferricyanide. Can I take the ferrocyanide form ?

Comment: It looks like you follow the idea similar name = similar behavior. Such an idea may accidentally work, but I would not rely on such luck.

Comment: No. Ferricyanide is Fe3+, ferrocyanide is Fe2+. Different compounds with different chemical properties

Comment: Why do you use calcium ferrocyanide ? This substance is soluble in water. Calcium ferricyanide is also soluble in water.

Comment: @Maurice After reading the question, I have found some youtube video that shows ferrocyanide forms white precipitate with calcium ions. But I assume it would not be very selective. The old good school method of bubbling CO2 through alkalized solution could be better.

Comment: According to the Handbook of Chemistry and Physics, Calcium ferricyanide is deliquescent and "very soluble" in water. Calcium ferrocyanide has a solubility of $86.8$ g in $100$ mL water at $25$°C.

Comment: [Although potasium ferrocyanide is recommended for the calcium test](https://pubs.acs.org/doi/pdf/10.1021/ja01959a010), you can technically use potassium ferricyanide, but there is a chance [you will get a mixed salt containing ferriferrocyanide, giving you false positive](https://pubs.acs.org/doi/pdf/10.1021/ja02267a003)