# Differentiating Ca2+ and Sr2+ ion

Tags: analytical-chemistry, salt

$\ce{Ca^{+2}}$ and $\ce{Sr^{+2}}$ both give a bit similar red color in flame test. What is the easiest way (chemical test) to distinguish $\ce{Ca^{+2}}$ and $\ce{Sr^{+2}}$?

Comment: What have you searched so far?

Comment: Use Potassium ferrocyanide solution, you will get a mixed salt of calcium (white ppt).

Comment: @AChem [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IOmbD.jpg) is what my tb says.

Comment: @Shub, Are you concerned about similar flame colors? I agree. Since this is a state approved textbook, I gather you will have to follow that. This video is from India (NCERT) and it explains how to distinguish the three ions. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=HzbEfWqzBhs

Comment: **Simplest** tests would be visual emission spectroscopy or mass spectroscopy... A *single* test would show all three species present and *their proportions*. That said, to pass *your* test, use the required response.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Magnesium vs calcium vs barium ions from these 3 tests](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/167911/magnesium-vs-calcium-vs-barium-ions-from-these-3-tests)

Comment: You can differentiate based on the solubility of their sulfates. Please see my answer^

Comment: @CHEMUMAN Good time plugging my comment: https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/170053/can-i-use-potassium-ferricyanide-instead-of-potassium-ferrocyanide-for-the-ident#comment357032_170053 (it has one paper linked on this test)

Comment: So Ca+2 will give white ppt in potassium ferrocyanide and none in Ba+2 and Sr+2? @NilayGhosh

Comment: @NilayGhosh Actually, I hadn't seen that question before. I have read about this test in my chemistry class few days ago only. Btw you have mentioned about mixed salt when tested in **ferricyanide** solution.

Comment: @Shub No, only barium and magnesium interfere with the test. I have addressed in a separate answer.

Comment: @CHEMUMAN Essentially yes. Ferricyanide is a different species and if it is used, it might give a mixture of ferricyanide + ferriferrocyanide precipitate giving a false positive. Nobody has confirmed it though since potassium ferrocyanide test works so well but I assume that happening as mentioned in the second paper linked.

Answer (score 4):

The video document given by AChem is not really clear. It should be replaced by the following method, used in my university.

Let's start from $5$ mL of an initial solution containing possibly any one or all of the three ions $\ce{Ca^{2+}, Sr^{2+}, Ba^{2+}}$.

§$1$. Check if this initial solution contains the ion $\ce{Ba^{2+}}$ by taking $3$ drops of the initial solution, adding $3$ drops of $0.1$ M $\ce{K2Cr2O7}$ plus $1$ mL $0.1$ M $\ce{CH3COONa}$. If a yellow precipitate appears, it means that **Barium** is present in solution : Go to $§2$.
If the solution remains clear, the solution does not contain $\ce{Ba^{2+}}$ : skip §$2$, and go to §$3$ with the rest of the initial solution.

§$2$. Add the following solutions to the rest of the initial solution : first $3$ mL $0.1$ M $\ce{K2Cr2O7}$ solution, plus $5$ mL $0.1$ M $\ce{CH3COONa}$. Filtrate the yellow $\ce{BaCrO4}$ precipitate. The filtrate must be yellow, and does not contain $\ce{Ba^{2+}}$ any more.

§$3$. Add enough $\ce{Na2CO3}$ to make the solution basic (pH > $8$). Heat to boiling temperature, cool, filter and wash the precipitate containing $\ce{CaCO3 + SrCO3}$. Throw away the yellow filtrate.

$§4$. Add enough $\ce{HNO3}$ to dissolve the precipitate. Usually $1$ mL $1$ M $\ce{HNO3}$ is enough. Drop the liquid in a ceramic capsule. Heat it so as to evaporate it totally, and to eliminate all crystallization waters. Then cool it down and add $1$ mL $100$% pure ethanol. Grind the stuff with a glass stick. Filtrate on a small filter paper. Wash twice with $0.5$ mL pure ethanol ($100$%). The residual insoluble part is made of $\ce{Sr(NO3)2}$. See how to use the filtrate in $§6$.

§$5$. The obtained residue of $\ce{Sr(NO3)2}$ is washed several times to eliminate traces of Calcium nitrate. Dissolve it in $3$ mL water. Add $1$ mL 1 M $\ce{H2SO4}$. A white precipitate is produced if the substance contains **Strontium**. Go to §6 with the filtrate.

§$6$. The filtrate contains calcium nitrate. It can be proven by first evaporating to dryness. Then the residue is dissolved in $1$ mL water. $1$ drop $1$ M $\ce{CH3COOH}$ is added to the obtained solution. The $1$ mL $0.1$ M ammonium oxalate is added. A white $\ce{CaC2O4}$ precipitate shows the presence of **Calcium**.

Comment: +1 Although the protocol is useful and superior, but students have *no* option to change texbook protocols, this is why I suggested that the OP follow his local teaching scheme for state exams.

Answer (score 2):

A good test for distinguishing calcium ions and strontium ions is **potassium ferrocyanide test.**

$$\ce{Ca^2+ + 2K4[Fe(CN)6] -> \underset{white}{K2Ca[Fe(CN)6]} \downarrow}$$

In presence of ammonium chloride, test is more sensitive. In this case, potassium is replaced by ammonium ions in the precipitate. However, the downside of this test is barium and magnesium interfere. You can separate them as discussed [in my other answer.](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/a/167916/17368). You can find more details on this test on a paper [linked in a previous comment of mine](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/170053/can-i-use-potassium-ferricyanide-instead-of-potassium-ferrocyanide-for-the-ident#comment357032_170053). However, the best test is checking the solubility of the corresponding sulfates (explained in my other answer).

Comment: What happens to Strontium with ferrocyanide ? Does it precipitate ?

Comment: @Maurice No, it won't precipitate.

Comment: And how will barium and magnesium interfere ?

Comment: @Maurice barium and magnesium also give precipitation with pot. Ferrocyanide. See: https://pubs.acs.org/doi/pdf/10.1021/ja01959a010. So, they recommend separating barium and magnesium first and using this test to confirm the presence of calcium.

Comment: So, there is just and only Strontium which does not make a precipitate with ferrocyanide ions. It seems strange !